# Output just a single value if a string is in a column

Tags: sql

Was expecting to find easy way for this but I haven't found any question that's similar to mine (I probably worded my question differently)

Suppose I have two tables:

Table1: Booking

| BookingID |
| --- |
| ABC123 |
| DEF456 |

Table2: BookingDesc

| BookingID | Route |
| --- | --- |
| ABC123 | A to B |
| ABC123 | B to C |
| ABC123 | C to A |
| DEF456 | D to E |
| DEF456 | E to F |

What I am hoping to achieve is as below:

| BookingID | related_to_D |
| --- | --- |
| ABC123 | No |
| DEF456 | Yes |

Basically, the "related_to_D" field checks if the character "D" exist in the column, not just a row at a time.

The best I can do now is:

```
SELECT b.BookingID,
CASE WHEN bd.Route LIKE '%D%' THEN 'YES'
ELSE 'NO' END AS related_to_D
FROM Booking b
JOIN BookingDesc bd
ON b.BookingID = bd.BookingID
```

which would give me:

| BookingID | related_to_D |
| --- | --- |
| ABC123 | NO |
| ABC123 | NO |
| ABC123 | NO |
| DEF456 | YES |
| DEF456 | NO |

Is there any function/easy way to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should have separate `from` and  `to` columns.

Comment: Dumb q, but how would MAX() register "YES" as the higher value? Is it by the length of the string?

Comment: Since 'YES' > 'NO', MAX() will give you 'YES' if BookingID has a 'YES' row.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use a `case` *expression* to do *conditional aggregation*. `YES` will be returned if at least one of a BookingID's routes contains D.

```
SELECT b.BookingID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bd.Route LIKE '%D%' THEN 'YES'
                ELSE 'NO' END) AS related_to_D
FROM Booking b
JOIN BookingDesc bd
  ON b.BookingID = bd.BookingID
GROUP BY b.BookingID
```

Comment: A more idiomatic way of doing this, if more verbose, is `IIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN bd.Route LIKE '%D%' THEN 1 END) > 0, 'YES', 'NO')`

Comment: @Charlieface, the <sql> tag alone means I give an ISO/ANSI SQL answer.

Comment: OK whatever, you can do `CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN bd.Route LIKE '%D%' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END` my point is the same

Comment: @Charlieface, now I see what you meant. (I got lost at IIF.) Matter of taste, same result.